# Supporting lexical-scope ScriptBlock parameters (e.g. Where-Object)

Tags: function, powershell, scope, closures, scriptblock

Consider the following arbitrary function and test cases:

```
Function Foo-MyBar {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ScriptBlock] $Filter
    )

    if (!$Filter) { 
        $Filter = { $true } 
    }

    #$Filter = $Filter.GetNewClosure()

    Get-ChildItem "$env:SYSTEMROOT" | Where-Object $Filter   
}

##################################

$private:pattern = 'T*'

Get-Help Foo-MyBar -Detailed

Write-Host "`n`nUnfiltered..."
Foo-MyBar

Write-Host "`n`nTest 1:. Piped through Where-Object..."
Foo-MyBar | Where-Object { $_.Name -ilike $private:pattern  }

Write-Host "`n`nTest 2:. Supplied a naiive -Filter parameter"
Foo-MyBar -Filter { $_.Name -ilike $private:pattern }
```

In Test 1, we pipe the results of `Foo-MyBar` through a `Where-Object` filter, which compares the objects returned to a pattern contained in a private-scoped variable `$private:pattern`.  In this case, this correctly returns all the files/folders in C:\ which start with the letter `T`.

In Test 2, we pass the same filtering script directly as a parameter to `Foo-MyBar`.  However, by the time `Foo-MyBar` gets to running the filter, `$private:pattern` is not in scope, and so this returns no items.

I understand *why* this is the case -- because the ScriptBlock passed to `Foo-MyBar` is not a *closure*, so does not close over the `$private:pattern` variable and that variable is lost.

*I note from comments that I previously had a flawed third test, which tried to pass {...}.GetNewClosure(), but this does not close over private-scoped variables -- thanks @PetSerAl for helping me clarify that.*

The question is, **how does `Where-Object` capture the value of `$private:pattern` in Test 1, and how do we achieve the same behaviour in our own functions/cmdlets?**

*(Preferably without requiring the caller to have to know about closures, or know to pass their filter script as a closure.)*

I note that, if I uncomment the `$Filter = $Filter.GetNewClosure()` line inside `Foo-MyBar`, then it never returns any results, because `$private:pattern` is lost.

(As I said at the top, the function and parameter are arbitrary here, as a shortest-form reproduction of my real problem!)

Comment: Can you recheck Test 3? As far as I know `GetNewClosure` does not capture `private` variables.

Comment: @PetSerAl - you might be right, although now I'm experiencing different behaviour in one ISE window (not tab) to another.  In the ISE window I was testing in, `$private:pattern` *is* being closed over, but I can't recreate in a fresh window.  Question stands, though, given Test 1 still works as described.

Comment: @PetSerAl - OK, `Remove-Variable pattern` reset it -- I must have defined `$pattern` at some point earlier.  I'll update to remove reference to Test 3

Comment: Simple way to solve it would be to put `Foo-MyBar` in separate module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example given does not work because calling a function will enter a new scope by default.  `Where-Object` will still invoke the filter script without entering one, but the scope of the function does not have the `private` variable.

There's three ways around this.

### Put the function in a different module than the caller

Every module has a `SessionState` which has its own stack of `SessionStateScope`s.  Every `ScriptBlock` is tied to the `SessionState` is was parsed in.

If you call a function defined in a module, a new scope is created within that module's `SessionState`, but not within the top level `SessionState`.  Therefore when `Where-Object` invokes the filter script without entering a new scope, it does so on the current scope for the `SessionState` to which that `ScriptBlock` is tied.

This is a bit fragile, because if you want to call that function from your module, well you can't.  It'll have the same issue.

### Call the function with the dot source operator

You most likely already know the dot-source operator (`.`) for invoking script files without creating a new scope.  That also works with command names and `ScriptBlock` objects.

```
. { 'same scope' }
. Foo-MyBar
```

Note, however, that this will invoke the function within the current scope of the `SessionState` *that the function is from*, so you cannot rely on `.` to always execute in the *caller's* current scope. Therefore, if you invoke functions associated with a different `SessionState` with the dot-source operator - such as functions defined in a (different) module - it may have unintended effects.  Variables created will persist to future function invocations and any helper functions defined within the function itself will also persist.

### Write a Cmdlet

Compiled commands (cmdlets) do not create a new scope when invoked.  You can also use similar API's to what `Where-Object` use (though not the exact same ones)

Here's a rough implementation of how you could implement `Where-Object` using public API's

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace MyModule
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsLifecycle.Invoke, "FooMyBar")]
    public class InvokeFooMyBarCommand : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
        public PSObject InputObject { get; set; }

        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        public ScriptBlock FilterScript { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            var filterResult = InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(
                useLocalScope: false,
                scriptBlock: FilterScript,
                input: null,
                args: new[] { InputObject });

            if (LanguagePrimitives.IsTrue(filterResult))
            {
                WriteObject(filterResult, enumerateCollection: true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked extending PSCmdlet, this should be the accepted answer, +1

Comment: @mklement0 in the scenario of a caller from outside of a module dot sourcing a function from a module, the current scope would most likely be the highest scope for the session state. Basically dot sourcing something from a different session state will not cause it to be invoked in *your* current scope, but the current scope of the session state (module) the command is tied to. [Additional reading](https://seeminglyscience.github.io/powershell/2017/09/30/Invocation-Operators-states-and-scopes)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; to call this behavior suprising is an understatment. Re target scope inside module: could it ever be something other than the module's _top-level_ scope?
The link to your blog is broken, because the path component isn't all-lowercase; here's the working link: https://seeminglyscience.github.io/powershell/2017/09/30/invocation-operators-states-and-scopes

Comment: @mklement0 good question! Yes it can, but it's a lot less likely.  Lets say `ModuleA` has `FunctionA` and `FunctionB`, and `ModuleB` has `FunctionC`.  If `FunctionA` calls `FunctionC` and `FunctionC` dot sources `FunctionB`, then `FunctionB` will be invoked in the scope created by the invocation of `FunctionA`.  Hopefully that is at least vaguely comprehensible... scopes are... complicated.  Also thank you for the URL correction! Autocorrect strikes again.

Comment: Just to make it more complicated: scopes are not stack but tree, because single parent scope can have multiple active child scopes in the same time.

Comment: @mklement0 [For example](https://tio.run/##ZU/BDoIwDL3vKxrCYYtA3EFu3j15IdGjKctAEmBkG3pQvn1iJUpiD21f3mtfO5i7tu6q2zaEauyVb0wPFTwYzDGgxY5T@474iJ1OfrDwaD1BQbnUddMvoyRA2K9V02epNUo7t9KdbeN1ejDOQ0QeEHPO6xsgpIUyg4atyE7YjnqzEeKPlCsy@i5N4stiOjFGl8icMZllO3jODyJIqiXkVBVIGcIL): each instance of `f` have its own `-Scope 0` `$a`, but `-Scope 1` `$a` is shared between them.

Comment: Revisiting this, I realized that the cmdlet implementation in this answer works in principle, but the `ScriptBlock` argument doesn't support use of `$_` to refer to the current pipeline object (that object is passed via a positional argument instead). The workaround is cumbersome - see [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3581) and, for a solution written in PowerShell, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53327851/45375).

Answer (score 6):

> how does `Where-Object` capture the value of `$private:pattern` in Test 1

As can be seen in [the source code for `Where-Object` in PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/4fc784e840b8df00d2552045c6ed52d027659d2b/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/InternalCommands.cs#L1571), PowerShell internally invokes the filter script *without confining it to its own local scope* (`_script` is the private backing field for the `FilterScript` parameter, notice the `useLocalScope: false` argument passed to `DoInvokeReturnAsIs()`):

```csharp
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    if (_inputObject == AutomationNull.Value)
        return;

    if (_script != null)
    {
        object result = _script.DoInvokeReturnAsIs(
            useLocalScope: false, // <-- notice this named argument right here
            errorHandlingBehavior: ScriptBlock.ErrorHandlingBehavior.WriteToCurrentErrorPipe,
            dollarUnder: InputObject,
            input: new object[] { _inputObject },
            scriptThis: AutomationNull.Value,
            args: Utils.EmptyArray<object>());

        if (_toBoolSite.Target.Invoke(_toBoolSite, result))
        {
            WriteObject(InputObject);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

> how do we achieve the same behaviour in our own functions/cmdlets?

**We don't** - `DoInvokeReturnAsIs()` (and similar scriptblock invocation facilities) are marked `internal` and can therefore only be invoked by types contained in the `System.Management.Automation` assembly