# Delay-bind script block does not work when function is exported from module

Tags: powershell, scope, powershell-core

I have following function:

```
function PipeScript {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Object] $InputObject,

        [Object] $ScriptBlock
    )

    process {
        $value = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
        Write-Host "Script: $value"
    }
}
```

When I define this function directly in script and pipe input into it I get following result which is expected:

```
@{ Name = 'Test' } | PipeScript -ScriptBlock { $_.Name }

# Outputs: "Script: Test"
```

But when I define this function inside module and export it with `Export-ModuleMember -Function PipeScript` then pipeline variable `$_` inside script block is always `null`:

```
Import-Module PipeModule
@{ Name = 'Test' } | PipeScript -ScriptBlock { $_.Name }

# Outputs: "Script: "
```

Full repro is available at: https://github.com/lpatalas/DelayBindScriptBlock

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for all his help.</sup>

Here's a **simple solution**, but note that it **runs the script block *directly* in the caller's scope**, i.e. it effectively "dot-sources", which allows modification of the caller's variables.

By contrast, your use of `Invoke-Command` runs the script block in a *child* scope of the caller's scope - if that is truly the intent, see the variant solution below.

"Dot-sourcing" the script block is also what standard cmdlets such as `Where-Object` and `ForEach-Object` do.

```
# Define the function in an (in-memory) module.
# An in-memory module is automatically imported.
$null = New-Module {

  function PipeScript {
    param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
      [Object] $InputObject
      ,
      [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
    )

    process {

      # Use ForEach-Object to create the automatic $_ variable
      # in the script block's origin scope.
      $value = ForEach-Object -Process $ScriptBlock -InputObject $InputObject

      # Output the value
      "Script: $value"
    }

  }

}

# Test the function:
$var = 42; @{ Name = 'Test' } | PipeScript -ScriptBlock { $_.Name; ++$var }
$var # -> 43 - the script block ran in the caller's scope.
```

The above outputs string `Script: Test` and `43` afterwards, proving that the input object was seen as `$_` and that dot-sourcing worked (`$var` was successfully incremented in the caller's scope).

---

Here's a **variant**, via the PowerShell SDK, that **runs the script block in a *child* scope of the caller's scope**.

This can be helpful if you don't want the execution of the script block to accidentally modify the caller's variables.

It is the same behavior you get with the engine-level delay-bind script-block and calculated-property features - though [it's unclear whether that behavior was chosen intentionally](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157).

```
$null = New-Module {

  function PipeScript {
    param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
      [Object] $InputObject
      ,
      [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
    )

    process {
      # Use ScriptBlock.InvokeContext() to inject a $_ variable
      # into the child scope that the script block runs in:
      # Creating a custom version of what is normally an *automatic* variable
      # seems hacky, but the docs do state:
      # "The list of variables may include the special variables 
      #  $input, $_ and $this." - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext
      $value = $ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext(
        $null, # extra functions to define (none here)
        [psvariable]::new('_', $InputObject) # actual parameter type is List<PSVariable>
      )
      # Output the value
      "Script: $value"
    }

  }

}

# Test the function:
$var = 42
@{ Name = 'Test' } | PipeScript -ScriptBlock { $_.Name; ++$var }
$var # -> 42 - unaltered, because the script block ran in a child scope.
```

The above outputs string `Script: Test`, followed by `42`, proving that the script block saw the input object as `$_` and that variable `$var` - although *seen* in the script block, was not *modified*, due to running in a child scope.

The `ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext()` method is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).

---

As for **why your attempt didn't work**:

- Generally, script blocks are bound to the scope and scope domain in which they are *created* (except if they're created expressly as *unbound* script blocks, with `[scriptblock]::Create('...')`).
- A scope outside of a module is part of the default scope domain. Every module has its own scope domain, and except for the global scope, which all scopes across all scope domains see, scopes in different scope domains do not see one another.
- Your script block is created in the default scope domain, and when the module-defined function invokes it, the `$_` is looked for *in the scope of origin*, i.e., in the (non-module) *caller* scope, where it isn't defined, because the automatic `$_` variable is created by PowerShell on demand in the *local* scope, which is in the enclosing module's scope domain.
- By using `.InvokeWithContext()`, the script block runs in a *child* scope of the caller's scope (as would be the case with `.Invoke()` and `Invoke-Command` by default), into which the above code *injects a custom `$_` variable* so that the script block can reference it.

---

Providing **better SDK support** for these scenarios is being discussed in [GitHub issue #3581](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3581).